# Loading a Javascript reference via JavaScript and calling it immediately from the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following code to load jQuery in a document from a certain website

```
j=document.createElement("SCRIPT");
j.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(j);
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

If I run this as a block from the console, I get

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

However, if I enter each line manually, the last line runs fine and I don't get the exception.

Is there something I'm missing -- maybe the DOM needs a few more milliseconds to finish processing the previous command?

Whatever the problem is, does any one know how to resolve this situation?

This occurs in chrome and firefox with dev tools and firebug respectively.

Comment: It's not so much that the DOM needs time to process a command. You've simply pushed a script tag on the DOM, but since it's an external reference it will be downloaded and run asynchronously. By running the next command you're making the assumption that the download and script interpretation is complete. It's likely not, hence the undefined error. Since you've tagged this with "google-chrome", I'll say that the onload function will work, but that doesn't work in every browser, so be aware your mileage will vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
j=document.createElement("SCRIPT");

j.onload = function(){
    window.J = jQuery.noConflict();
};

j.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js";
document.body.appendChild(j);
```

Comment: If you don't want jQuery to be accessible as the `jQuery` variable, you want to instead do `J = jQuery.noConflict( true );`.

Comment: Until Esalija accepts the change, do be a good person and append the script to the document.head, not document.body!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the last line with this:

```
function checkJQuery() {
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        setTimeout('checkJQuery', 50);
    }
    else {
        J = jQuery.noConflict();
        J(function() {
            // Document ready stuff here
        });
    }
}

checkJQuery();
```

Comment: Looks like dzejkej beat me to the punch on the setTimeout. Credit where it's due!

Comment: It's possible that jQuery will never load, for example if jquery.com was down for some reason. Esalija's `onload` based solution is the way to go. You can also hook into `onerror`.

Comment: @Coronus I deleted my answer because Esalija's solution is a lot better one :).